# Help with my post

Tags: support

I posted my first question on Arqade and it received three downvotes:

[Half Life 2, Episode 1 starts running slow in-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258819/half-life-2-episode-1-starts-running-slow-in-game?noredirect=1#comment360655_258819)

Does this meta site allow newbies to get feedback on their post? I was hoping the downvoters would help me out under the comments, but they didn't respond to my cry for help :-)

I'm more than happy to delete the question, but for now I'll let it simmer in shame so the link won't die here in meta.

Comment: Just one minor thing: You forgot to add a game tag. I added the half-life 2 tag to your question right now.

Comment: @MrLemon - I saw, thanks for that. I didn't know there were tags for individual games. I really appreciate all of your patience and help. What a nice stack!

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry about it. Your question is a good example of 'Tech Support' done right. A lot of our issues surrounding Tech Support questions on Arqade have to do with inadequate information being presented by the asker, amounting to *"<Game> doesn't work, HALP"*. In your case, you've provided:

- Explanation and context of the problem
- System specs
- Game settings
- Troubleshooting steps you've taken,

and most importantly

- **Feedback**, responding to comments and editing in new information as it becomes relevant.

---

#### So why are you receiving downvotes?

Because [Tim Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/179041).

On a more serious note, Tech Support *is* one of the many small dividing lines for this community; There is a small (but not insignificant) group of users who don't think we should deal with Tech Support-style questions here. Your downvotes *could* be a result of that stance, or it could've been one downvote that spiraled into three because monkey see monkey do. Who knows!

As LessPop_MoreFizz mentions in the comments on the post, if people thought the post was 'fixable' in some way, they would've told you (or fixed it themselves). Either way, I wouldn't worry too much :)

Comment: It's worth noting that upvotes grant more reputation than downvotes take away to make it easier to forgive Tim Post's airheadedness.

Answer (score 2):

I originally downvoted because I lost my keys.  That, and I thought you could have done a little more to narrow the problem.  Perhaps confirm if there is any problem with the lowest settings and then work upwards.  Just a glance at the question indicates you have the highest settings on for more settings and pretty much wondering what you can do to improve performance.

It seems like a no-brainer to suggest working upwards from the lowest settings to finding a point at which your machine runs the game smoothly.  Hey, maybe you find the same problem on the lowest settings.  There are third party plugins/tools etc that can check if your current machine is capable of running a game.

Anti-virus kicking off a scan mid-game always grinds your game to a halt.  Not sure if you checked for that already.

Also, when people comment/ask why the downvote it tends to lead to more downvotes.  I'm not saying that is my reason, just that it can be a reason for downvotes.

Anyway, I found my keys this morning so removed my downvote.

Comment: Many thanks for your elaborations. Glad you found your keys +1. I don't wish to start a defense, but the core of the thing is that the game runs fine for quite a while. Settings like texture detail and shadows tend to slow the game from the start. I should have made that explicit. Also, the fact that it consistently happens, albeit after a variable time excludes the virus scan issue. However, I do appreciate that comment and I will check on those settings straight away! Thanks.

Comment: @Christiaan - If you want upvotes, you need to ask a useful question. I'm not sure that is your concern (you have a real problem, and will be satisfied when you get to the bottom of it).  Really, on the face of it, the question should be highly rated if plenty of other people have the same problem. You don't have to worry about defending against downvotes. Respond to comments, keep the question updated with your findings and you will find the answer eventually.